# UIView animation trying to change the frame size doesn't work in iOS 8 but in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios8, uianimation

I wanted to resize an UIView, my code works perfect in iOS 7.1 but when I run it in iOS 8 it didn't work properly (I will explain below).

I have my UIView int the storyboard with values (0,67,511,320), I want to resize to full screen on iPad, so I added the following code:

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

            CGRect frame = containerView.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            frame.origin.y = 67;
            frame.size.height = 643;
            frame.size.width = 1024;
            containerView.frame = frame;
            ...

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            ...
        }];
```

I wanted something like:

```
 _________________________________
|           |                     |
|           |                     |
|     A     |                     |
|___________|                     |
|                                 |
|                BACKGROUND       |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|_________________________________|

                |
                V
 _________________________________
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|               A                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|_________________________________|
```

But it starts the animation like (0,67,0,0) to (0,67,511,320)

Any clue about what is happening? Or alternative?

Comment: Note that you don't need to get the frame from the `containerView.frame` when overwriting all members, as you do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should disable pregenerated constraints. The most simple way is to use autoresizing masks instead of constraints for animating view.

```
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

You can put this code to your `-viewDidLoad` method or just above `[UIView animateWithDuration:...`

Comment: what should be the contrainerView if I have scrollview and uiview inside of scrollview and animations happening inside this uiview. Would it be that uiview?

Answer (score 5):

is autolayout enabled?
maybe in iOS 8 some additional constrains are adding during build time

try to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` in animatin block, after animation code itself

**UPDATE**

```
__block CGRect frame = containerView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 67;
frame.size.height = 643;
frame.size.width = 1024;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        containerView.frame = frame;
        ...

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ...
    }];
```

Comment: I add my views in storyboard, how i could disable this?

Comment: Did [self.view layoutIfNeeded] help ? Also look how to animate view with constrints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626802/animating-uiview-frame-with-constraints

Comment: It doesn't work but I finally solved it with @LorikMalork answer thanks for your help!